# Salary form calculations HTML, Joomla, Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, joomla3.0

I'm working on a Joomla site and trying to figure out how to create a form or section for calculating salary.

I'm thinking a form and ideally a slider below form for the second field (invoiced sum).

First field I'd want to have input birth year.
Second field I'd want to have input invoiced sum.
Third field I'd want to have the calculated sum.

Problem I'm having is the birth year value, since taxing depends on when you're born.

For example;
76 years or older: 0%
67-75 years: 10.21%
26-66 years: 31.42%
25 or younger: 15.49%

So that the first input birth year and correct tax calculates with invoiced sum to get salary calculation.

And icing on the cake would be if a slider below also could to affect the same field as input invoiced value.

I've seen several pages in my native langue though that have this and I'd like to "copy" the function.

Thanks in advance for all tips and tricks.

Comment: This is very broad. Can you clarify which aspect of the job you are stuck with? Try  to break it down into pieces. What do you need to know *first*? Stack Overflow works best with specific, focused technical questions. The broader the less likely a question is to work here.

Comment: Well...Probably the input with birth year is the one giving me most headache.